# .net input currency format in a text field (from right to left)using angularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

Here an expamle what I want .

the amount entered in U.S. currency format by displaying a decimal point as customers enter the the dollar value.  Example:if user entered 1 -> .01 and 1234 -> 12.34.
or 123456 -> 1234.56

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the amount entered in U.S. currency format by displaying a decimal
> point as customers enter the the dollar value. Example:if user entered
> 1 -> .01 and 1234 -> 12.34. or 123456 -> 1234.56

From your description, the entered value divided by 100 will return the required value. So, you could use the `blur` event to change the data format, code as below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>Write something in the input field:</p>
        <input type="text" ng-blur="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
        <p>{{myValue}}</p> 
    </div>

    <script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        $scope.myFunc = function () {
            $scope.myValue = ($scope.myValue / 100).toFixed(2);  
        }; 
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, for the currency format, we usually set the format with commas, you could refer this sample:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>Write something in the input field:</p> 
        <input type="text" ng-blur="myFunc2()" ng-model="myValue2" />
        <p>{{myValue2}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        $scope.myFunc2 = function () { 
            const value = $scope.myValue2.replace(/,/g, '') / 100;
            $scope.myValue2 = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                style: 'decimal',
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                minimumFractionDigits: 2
            });
        };
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

The output like this:

[image]

[**Note**] By using the above method, the entered value divided by 100 will return the required value, if the entered value is a float value, by using the above code, the returned value will not equal the entered value. If you want to prevent it, remove the division action (`/100`).